# Overriding clen method and call super in it

Tags: python, django, admin, super

I have problem with overiding clean method.
In ModelAdmin i set my own clean function,

```
form = MyModelAdminForm
```

I don't know how to call in it super method,
At now when someone doesn't fill other requested fields 
appear yellow screen﻿

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__'

def clean(self):

    if (myCond):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Message")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is well documented in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        # get cleaned data first
        cleaned_data = super(MyModelAdminForm, self).clean()  # for python 2
        cleaned_data = super().clean()  # for python 3

        if myCond:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Message")
```